# Is there a way to change an authenticated user id right before they are created in Firebase. They are created by the facebook provider

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

We are in the process of moving our MongoDB database to Firebase with firestore. Right now we have a Firebase application where we use the firestore to save data about each user. We want to use the Firebase authentication to log in our users. We already have users inside our firestore who have a Facebook id inside their User document inside the Firestore which we want to use to create an Auth account.

We can not create a facebook user programmatically using cloud functions. So the solution we thought of is when a user gets created (by a facebook user logging in) we make a cloud function that checks if the new Facebook user's id already exists inside our firestore. This does not work since the authentication uid is defined on creation and we can not change it. We want this authentication id to be the same as that user's document name.

---

## Solutions we thought of

#### New collection that redirects new users

Our first plan was to make a new collection of documents which we'd make facebook user's uids get redirected to their document with their old uid.

The problem with this approach is that we'd have to read from this new document *every* time we were going to look up this person. And this would essentially double our reads and double the price of our firestore bill.

#### Changing the document names

The other plan was to change the names of the document of the user. This would make us able to treat the new authenticated user as a normal user without too much change. And it can be automated.

The problem with this approach is that we have to change all the references made to the user which can lead to a lot of reads and extra work. All of the games the user has played, all their friendships. And with hundred thousands of users this can lead up to a lot. And a lot can go wrong with this.

---

We are trying to figure out on how we can fix this problem. We would love any feedback or suggestions which can push us in the right direction. If there is anything unclear, I'd love to hear questions. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this by using a combination of a firebase auth trigger and custom claims.

**Auth trigger**

First, create a firebase auth trigger function, which will fire up after the user account has been created.

```
import { auth } from 'firebase-functions';

export const onUserCreate = auth.user().onCreate((user) => { ... })
```

Inside the trigger function, you can read the document that you need once, and add its value to a custom user claim by using the admin sdk.

**Adding a claim**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

...
const claims = user.customClaims || {};
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { ...claims, oldFacebookId: "value here"  });
...
```

**Consuming claims**

While custom claims need to be added through admin sdk, they can be consumed clientside without any issues, when your user logs in.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        user?.getIdTokenResult().then((token) => {
          const oldFacebookId: token.claims.oldFacebookId;
          ... do what you need with it
         });

       return;
      }
});
```

By using the combination of `onAuthStateChanged` listener and `getIdTokenResult` you will be able to access the claim anytime your user is logged in or his state is being automatically refreshed by the firebase SDK on your app.

Comment: The facebook id is the same, it is the authentication id that needs to be changed. But still going with this approach. I will be able to save each person's "id" inside of the custom claim instead of using the authenticated uid. Would this have any downsides for my application?

Comment: There is a potential performance issue here. Auth trigger still cold starts, so it can take up to a few seconds for it to trigger and inject the claim to the user, so this would maybe need to be handled for the first login in case the user needs to login immediately after registering. if you are forcing them to validate the account first, this will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to control the UID of Firebase Authentication is by [creating a custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth). With that you can [create custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) with whatever UID you want in Cloud Functions or another trusted environment.